# Google Spreadsheet Filter by Condition and Filter by Color Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I use this script to make my spreadsheet auto sort base on certain column.

```
function filterandsort(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ['Sheet1']
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var sheetName = sheets[i]
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var range = sheet.getRange("A2:J1000");
      if (sheet != null) {
        range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
       
    
      }
    }
}
```

But I need more filter that will filter base on text and color.I can't find example for this function that I can combine with my script.

```
Filter by Condition -> Text Contains ->"word"
Filter by Color -> Fill Color -> "#000"
```

Why this filter need to put inside this script because even I already set on spreadsheet, when new data come and auto sort, previous filter by condition and color not work.Hope someone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query you need

- The Apps Script [filter class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter)
- The [filter criteria builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder)
- the filter criteria [whenTextContains()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whentextcontainstext) and `setVisibleBackgroundColor()`
- a builder for [newColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newcolor)

**The result could look like this:**

```js
function filterandsort(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ['Sheet1']
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var sheetName = sheets[i];
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var range = sheet.getRange("A2:J1000");
      if (sheet != null) {
        if(range.getFilter()){
        range.getFilter().remove();
        }
        var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleBackgroundColor(SpreadsheetApp.newColor().setRgbColor("#000").build()).whenTextContains("word").build();
        range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, filterCriteria);
        range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});        
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!